# How to pass array of struct as interface by reference

Tags: arrays, go, struct, interface

I am trying to read all documents under a given Firestore collection and return the documents as an array of struct. The log within the function output the data as the Firestore documents, but the array of struct outside of the function is always an empty array.

The function to read all documents under a collection.

```
func (fc *FirebaseClient) ReadCollection(collectionPath string, objects interface{}) error {
    ctx := context.Background()
    opt := option.WithCredentialsJSON([]byte(os.Getenv("FIREBASE_CREDENTIALS")))
    client, err := firestore.NewClient(ctx, os.Getenv("FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID"), opt)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer client.Close()

    collectionRef := client.Collection(collectionPath)
    docs, err := collectionRef.DocumentRefs(ctx).GetAll()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    log.Printf("Total documents: %i", len(docs))
    objs := make([]interface{}, len(docs))
    for i, doc := range docs {
        docsnap, err := doc.Get(ctx)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        if err := docsnap.DataTo(&objs[i]); err != nil {
            return err
        }
        log.Printf("obj: %v", objs[i])

    }

    objects = objs
    log.Printf("objects: %v", objects)
    return nil
}
```

The code to call the function

```
    var ss []SomeStruct

    fc := new(insightech.FirebaseClient)
    if err := fc.ReadCollection("mycollection", ss); err != nil {
        return
    }
```

`ss` is an empty array always.

The reason I don't want to specify the type of struct is make the ReadCollection function generic so I can call it to read different collections.

The code doesn't trigger any error, but the outcome is an empty array even though the `objects` interface is definitely an array with elements.

Comment: How could that ever work? Take a look at how the stdlib does such things e.g. in encoding/json.

Comment: Reassigning objects does nothing for the caller. It's the same as if you would pass, say, an int. Everything is passed by value in Go.

Comment: if the `interface{}` is assigned as a struct, it works. I can read a single document (different code to read a document instead of a collection) and update the values in the struct that's passed to the function.

Comment: that definitely should be a pointer as @mkopriva said

Comment: Sorry, I tried `fc.ReadCollection("mycollection", &ss)` but no difference.

Comment: @ChaomingLi You have to pass a pointer, there is no way around that, however your implementation has a lot more problems then just that so that's why "no difference".

Comment: Why are you passing an interface? You seem to know that it's a slice, so why not just pass a (pointer to a) slice?

Comment: @Flimzy because I don't know the struct type in the slice. I want to keep it flexible to handle different collections (e.g. user, room, etc) Each of these collections will have a struct to map the structure.

Comment: If I passed the result as `[]interface{}` alongside with `error`, use type assertion to assign the element one by one from the interface array to the struct array, it works. But that means extra code outside of the ReadCollection every time.

Comment: @ChaomingLi to make it work you should do something like this: https://play.golang.com/p/LWWPJZI7mXn (note i haven't actually tested that so there will, most probably, be bugs... but in general it should give you an idea of what you need to do)

Comment: @ChaomingLi one issue that i've already noticed is that i've used `reflect.AppendSlice` which is incorrect, it should be `reflect.Append(dest, obj.Elem())`

Comment: @mkopriva thank you. `dest` seems the array I want. but how can I modify `objects` to the pointer of `dest`?

Comment: @ChaomingLi https://play.golang.com/p/nX7na1NetcV fixed it up a bit, removed the firestore stuff so that it can be executed on playground and now you can see that the slice getting modified.

Comment: @ChaomingLi variation using append https://play.golang.com/p/nt6xg5qyRZh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @mkopriva, the following code works:

```
func (fc *FirebaseClient) ReadCollection(collectionPath string, objects interface{}) error {
    ctx := context.Background()
    opt := option.WithCredentialsJSON([]byte(os.Getenv("FIREBASE_CREDENTIALS")))
    client, err := firestore.NewClient(ctx, os.Getenv("FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID"), opt)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer client.Close()

    collectionRef := client.Collection(collectionPath)
    docs, err := collectionRef.DocumentRefs(ctx).GetAll()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    log.Printf("Total documents: %i", len(docs))

    dest := reflect.ValueOf(objects).Elem()


    log.Printf("dest: %v", dest)
    for _, doc := range docs {
        docsnap, err := doc.Get(ctx)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        obj := reflect.New(dest.Type().Elem())

        if err := docsnap.DataTo(obj.Interface()); err != nil {
            return err
        }
        log.Printf("obj: %v", obj)
        dest = reflect.Append(dest, obj.Elem())


    }

    reflect.ValueOf(objects).Elem().Set(dest)
    log.Printf("objects: %v", dest)
    return nil
}
```

```
    var ss []SomeStruct

    fc := new(insightech.FirebaseClient)
    if err := fc.ReadCollection("mycollection", &ss); err != nil {
        return
    }
```